# Flutter Android build not generating in Mac

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

In Mac, I've setup Flutter in Android studio. When I'm running project it gives me error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I'm using all latest versions of Flutter, Kotlin, Gradle etc.

Comment: Please share full error log

Answer (score 0):

You need to equalize kotlin version in first row which is `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` to according to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` of underlined `$kotlin_version`

After this, the problem will solve...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution for my problem. There are 2 dependency defined in .yaml file 1. geo_location and   2. location.

**After removing the location dependency from .yaml file and run command flutter pub get** I can successfully build android build from Mac. This solution might not be global but solution of my problem I found this.

Thank you!
Happy coding.